# Override/Customize AutoCAD Command

Tags: c#, overriding, autocad-plugin

Is there a way to override/customize an existing AutoCAD command?

When I'm calling...

```
Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
doc.SendStringToExecute("_.3DROTATE\n", true, false, true);
```

...it lets me choose objects, specify a basepoint and specify an angle.
I already have a saved basepoint so how do I set it in my code to avoid the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[At Walmsley blog](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/overrules/) you can find everything you want about overruling. Here is an example of command overruling :

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface;

namespace MyFirstOverrule
{
    // This is our custom DrawableOverrule class.
    // In this case we're just overruling WorldDraw

public class MyDrawOverrule : DrawableOverrule
{
    public override bool WorldDraw(Drawable drawable, WorldDraw wd)
    {
        // Cast Drawable to Line so we can access its methods and
        // properties
        Line ln = (Line)drawable;

        // Draw some graphics primitives
        wd.Geometry.Circle(ln.StartPoint + 0.5 * ln.Delta, ln.Length / 5, ln.Normal);

        // In this case we don't want the line to draw itself, nor do
        // we want ViewportDraw called
        return true;
    }
}
public class Commands
{
    //Shared member variable to store our Overrule instance
    private static MyDrawOverrule _drawOverrule;
    [CommandMethod("TOG")]
    public static void ToggleOverrule()
    {
        // Initialize Overrule if first time run
        if(_drawOverrule == null)
        {
            _drawOverrule = new MyDrawOverrule();
            Overrule.AddOverrule(RXObject.GetClass(typeof(Line)), _drawOverrule, false);
            Overrule.Overruling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Toggle Overruling on/off
            Overrule.Overruling = !Overrule.Overruling;
        }
        // Regen is required to update changes on screen
        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.Regen();
    }
    }
}
```